GitGuardian jenkins integration
I get an error when trying to integrate the GitGuardian ggshield with Jenkins. I followed the directions GitGuardian mentioned on their docs  at https://docs.gitguardian.com/ggshield-docs/integrations/cicd-integrations/jenkins-ci
Here is the pipeline script I am running in Jenkins:
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('GitGuardian Scan') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                        image 'gitguardian/ggshield:latest' 
                        args '--platform linux/amd64 -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash'
                }
                
            }
            environment {
                GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY = credentials('gitguardian-api-key')
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ggshield secret scan ci'
            }
        }
    }
}

I get the following error:
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 501:20 --platform linux/amd64 -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash -w /Users/myusername/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline -v /Users/myusername/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline:/Users/myusername/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline:rw,z -v /Users/myusername/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline@tmp:/Users/myusername/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** gitguardian/ggshield:latest cat
$ docker top <CONTAINER ID> -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: <ERROR ID>
java.io.IOException: Failed to run top '<CONTAINER ID>'. Error: Error response from daemon: container <CONTAINER ID> is not running
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.listProcess(DockerClient.java:155)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:323)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:105)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:140)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(Docker.groovy:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.declarative.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(DockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.declarative.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.configureRegistry(AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.declarative.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.run(AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:50)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.checkoutAndRun(CheckoutScript.groovy:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.doCheckout(CheckoutScript.groovy:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript.run(LabelScript.groovy:43)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:147)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:17)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:49)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:180)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:423)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE

